# Autocomplete Chained

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, chained

I'm working on a default JqueryUI Autocomplete and looking for further development of code. I have already worked and developed for chained auto search, but recent work by the developer has messed it up. I would like chained Autocomplete.

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

Looking for chained autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing to use jQuery UI https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: sorry what m asking is the code required for four input feild. with chained auto search. but if condition only works for two input.